# Trying to pass data using data tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a link with a data attribute to a DIV. When this DIV is clicked, I need to reload the page and call a function. I am trying to pass a data-attribute called url and on page refresh detect if the data url exists and execute the correct function. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I am using a sample URL for this example.

```
$('.activeCategory').html('<a href="http://www.test.com"' + 'data-url="www.test.com#path' + '">' + "www.test.com" + '</a>');

$('.activeCategory').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-url') == 'http://www.test.com#path') 
    { 
      exampleFunction();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think its just a matter of your concatenated string for the link.   From what I see, this is going to result in a string that looks like this in the html code: `<a href="http://www.test.com"data-url="www.test.com#path">` which, I think, is not what you were looking for.

Comment: Also, "this" is going to be the element that the event was attached to.  Ie. the `<div>` that has a class of "activeCategory" and it is not the element that has the attribute "data-url" its the `<a>` element inside "this" that does.   Confused?  I think I am :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the child before you can access its `data-url` (see snippet)

```js
$('.activeCategory').html(
'Click Me <a href="http://www.test.com"' + 'data-url="www.test.com#path' + '">' 
+ "www.test.com" + '</a>');

$('.activeCategory').click(function() {
  var url = $(this).children('a').data('url')
    if (url == 'www.test.com#path') 
    { 
      alert("data-url = \""+url+"\'")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="activeCategory"></div>
```

Alternately, you could also search the children by data-url as shown below:

```js
$('.activeCategory').html(
    'Click Me <a href="http://www.test.com"' + 'data-url="www.test.com#path' + '">' 
    + "www.test.com" + '</a>');

$('.activeCategory').click(function() {
  var link = $(this).children('a[data-url="www.test.com#path"]')
    if (link.length > 0) { 
      alert("data-url = \""+link.data('url')+"\'")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="activeCategory"></div>
```

Comment: What he said :)

Comment: You should consider using [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) functions instead of `attr('data-url')`.

Comment: @Noah thank you! this works. How can i refresh the page and call a function?

Comment: @Tom Do you mean if the data-url matches you want to call a function and then refresh the page?

Comment: @Noah yeah. the problem is that this function is already executed once on the page "displayTomatoes();" i need a way to refresh the page and reload it

Comment: @Tom I think you should ask a separate question with that code because I think I would need more code before I could answer.

Comment: Thanks Noah! Anyway your answer helps alot thank you

Comment: Glad I was able to help